# Pandas - Insert blank row for each group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1=pd.DataFrame({'group':[1,1,2,2,2],
             'value':[2,3,np.nan,5,4]})
df1

    group   value
0   1       2
1   1       3
2   2       NaN
3   2       5
4   2       4
```

I want to add a row after each group in which the value of `value` is `NaN` . The desire output is:

```
   group   value
0   1       2
1   1       3
2   1       NaN
3   2       NaN
4   2       5
5   2       4
6   2       NaN
```

In my real dataset I have a lot of groups and more columns besides `value`, I want all of them to be `NaN` in newly added row.

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 7):

#### `concat` with `append`

```
s = df1.groupby('group')
out = pd.concat([i.append({'value': np.nan}, ignore_index=True) for _, i in s])
out.group = out.group.ffill().astype(int)
```

#### `apply` with `append`<sup>[1]</sup>

```
df1.groupby('group').apply(
    lambda d: d.append({'group': d.name}, ignore_index=True).astype({'group': int})
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Both produce:

```
   group  value
0      1    2.0
1      1    3.0
2      1    NaN
3      2    NaN
4      2    5.0
5      2    4.0
6      2    NaN
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> This solution brought to you by your local [@piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2336654/pirsquared)

Comment: `df1.groupby('group').apply(lambda d: d.append({'group': d.name}, ignore_index=True)).reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: That's very clean :)

Comment: I can see it works, but how? Isn't `.apply(lambda d: ....)` be done on individual groups and not trickle through?

Comment: The lambda method changes all of my Booleans and integers to floats.

Answer (score 4):

Can also just `groupby`+`apply`, a one-liner

```
df.groupby('group').apply(lambda gr: gr.append(gr.tail(1).assign(value=np.nan))).reset_index(drop=True)
```

or to be explicit

```
g = df.groupby('group')
def f(gr):
    n = gr.tail(1).copy()
    n.value = np.nan
    return gr.append(n)
g.apply(f).reset_index(drop=True)


    group   value
0   1       2.0
1   1       3.0
2   1       NaN
3   2       NaN
4   2       5.0
5   2       4.0
6   2       NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to get a little creative:

```
(pd.concat([df1, 
            df1.groupby('group')['value'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(-1).iloc[-1]).reset_index()])
    .sort_values('group')
    .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
   group  value
0      1    2.0
1      1    3.0
2      1    NaN
3      2    NaN
4      2    5.0
5      2    4.0
6      2    NaN
```

Comment: Curious what the timings look like on OP's data set.

Comment: Extra points for not using `append`, which these days pandas cautions is deprecated and will be eventually removed.

Answer (score 2):

### My version of `concat`

```
ii = dict(ignore_index=True)
pd.concat([
    d.append({'group': n}, **ii) for n, d in df1.groupby('group')
], **ii).astype({'group': int})

   group  value
0      1    2.0
1      1    3.0
2      1    NaN
3      2    NaN
4      2    5.0
5      2    4.0
6      2    NaN
```